# Does Ethereum 2.0 still have use cases for oracles, why?

Tags: oracles, eth-2.0, validators

It seems to me Ethereum 2.0 would only require that one node creates blocks at a time, does that make unnecessary oracles.

Answer (score 6):

The basic ideas of blockchain remains the same in Ethereum 2.0; one of the basic concepts is they are *deterministic*. For our purposes that means that external data needs to be input into the blockchain. The way to do that is through various kinds of oracles.

So that will not change for Eth 2.0. External data still needs to come somehow into the blockchain and oracles will still work pretty much the same way they work now.